# Python - Adding a state to a program

Tags: python, sockets, select, client

I have this program that's supposed to take a user's lowercase sentence and capitalize it.  There's currently two states, one that takes in the message (which I think is referred to as sockCanSend) and the other that capitalizes it (sockCanReceive).  The problem is that I'm supposed to add another method/state so that the program is only in the send state if the buffer is completely empty and only goes to the receive state if the buffer is completely full.  The intermediate state should be accessed if the buffer is only partially full.  I think this intermediate state is supposed to continue accepting input up until the buffer is completely full, at which point it changes state to the send state.  Meanwhile, I think it's supposed to keep capitalizing the user's message so long as a message is received.  If you're in this state and the buffer is empty, there's some sort of problem and the connection should terminate.  The instructor for this course (it's a network course) didn't explain any of this very well and I've tried talking to him about it but his explanation still didn't make any sense.  I figured that in order to reach this new state I'd need a new method (sockCanSendOrRecv) but that's about all I know.  How can I add this new state?

```
from socket import *
from select import select
import sys                              # for exit

# select sets used to map sock#->function to call
rmap, wmap, xmap = {}, {}, {}           # read, write, except.
stop = 0                                # set to true when should stop (on socket failure)

# setup server socket
serverSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM) # ipv4, tcp
serverSock.bind(('', 2000))             # bind to port 2000
serverSock.listen(3)                    # up to 3 pending accepts
serverSock.setblocking(False)           # non-blocking (readable means accept will succeed)

# constants for connection state
readState = 0                           # when interested in reading
writeState = 1                          # when interested in writing
readOrWriteState = 2                    # when buffer is partially full

class connection:
    def __init__(self, sock):           # constructor
        sock.setblocking(False)
        print "new connection on fd %d" % sock.fileno()
        self.sock = sock
        self.buf = bytearray(1024)
        self.fd = fd = sock.fileno()
        self.state = readState
        xmap[fd] = lambda : self.sockError()   # call sockError on sock error
        self.setSelect()

    def sockCanReceive(self):
        "called when socket is ready for pending read"
        fd, buf = self.fd, self.buf
        self.start = 0
        self.nbytes = nbytes = self.sock.recv_into(buf, 1024)
        print "rec'd %d bytes on fd %d: <%s>" % (self.nbytes, fd, buf[0:nbytes])
        if nbytes != 0:                                # read succeeded
            buf[0:nbytes] = str(buf[0:nbytes]).upper() # convert to uppercase
            self.state = writeState
            self.setSelect()
        else:                           # socket closed
            print "zero length read from %d.  Assuming that other end is closed." % fd
            self.close()

    def sockCanSend(self):
        "called when socket is ready for pending write"
        fd = self.fd
        start = self.start              # first unsent
        toSend = self.nbytes - start    # number of bytes to send
        sent = self.sock.send(self.buf[start:toSend])
        self.start += sent
        print "sent %d bytes of %d on fd %d" % (sent, toSend, fd)
        if sent == toSend:              # all sent, switching to receive
            self.state = readState
            self.setSelect()

    def sockCanSendOrRecv(self):
        "called when buffer is partially full"


    def sockError(self):
        "called when socket is in error condition"
        fd = self.fd
        print "socket error for %d. Shutting down."
        self.close()
    def close(self):
        "close down this connection"
        fd = self.fd
        print "closing connection on fd %d" % fd
        for x in rmap, wmap, xmap:      # remove from select sets
            if x.has_key(fd): del x[fd]
        try:
            self.sock.close()
        except:
            pass
    def setSelect(self):
        "set select read/write sensitivity based on connection state"
        fd = self.fd
        if self.state == readState:
            rmap[fd] = lambda : self.sockCanReceive() # interested in reading
            if wmap.has_key(fd): del wmap[fd]   # not interested in writing
        else:  # writeState
            wmap[fd] = lambda : self.sockCanSend()    # interested in writing
            if rmap.has_key(fd): del rmap[fd]     # not interested in reading


def ssockAccept():
    "called when a client has connected to server sock"
    connSock, addr = serverSock.accept()
    print "accepted connection on fd %d from %s" % (connSock.fileno(), addr)
    connection(connSock)

def ssockPanic():
    "called when the server socket has failed"
    print "Panic: listener socket failed.  Aborting."
    sys.exit(1)

rmap[serverSock.fileno()] = ssockAccept # call ssockAccept() when client connects
xmap[serverSock.fileno()] = ssockPanic  # call ssockPanic() if socket fails

# this is the main select loop
while not stop:
    print "select(r=%s, w=%s, x=%s, 5s)" % (rmap.keys(), wmap.keys(), xmap.keys())
    r,w,x = select(rmap.keys(), wmap.keys(), xmap.keys(), 5)
    print "=======> returned: r=%s, w=%s, x=%s" % (r,w,x)
    for fd in r:
        rmap[fd]()                      # call read handler
    for fd in w:
        wmap[fd]()                      # call write handler
    for fd in x:
        xmap[fd]()                      # call eXception handler
```

Comment: Comments in python are denoted with a `#`, you shouldn't use the `"` characters for comments (Unless you want to do a lot of lines of comments which I believe `""" text """` is okay.

Comment: Those're docstrings, and they're legitimate.

Answer (score 0):

> I figured that in order to reach this new state I'd need a new method
>   (sockCanSendOrRecv) but that's about all I know.

You don't need a new method for the new state `readOrWriteState`; just extend `setSelect` to handle the state - e. g.

```
def setSelect(self):
    "set select read/write sensitivity based on connection state"
    fd = self.fd
    if self.state == readState:
        rmap[fd] = lambda : self.sockCanReceive() # interested in reading
        if wmap.has_key(fd): del wmap[fd]     # not interested in writing
    elif self.state == readOrWriteState:
        rmap[fd] = lambda : self.sockCanReceive() # interested in reading
        wmap[fd] = lambda : self.sockCanSend()    # interested in writing            
    else:  # writeState
        wmap[fd] = lambda : self.sockCanSend()    # interested in writing
        if rmap.has_key(fd): del rmap[fd]     # not interested in reading
```

- and adapt `sockCanReceive` to set `state` to `readOrWriteState` as long as the buffer is not full, `sockCanSend` to set `state` to `readOrWriteState` as long as the buffer is not empty, and both `sockCanReceive` and `sockCanSend` to be able to handle a partially full buffer.